# DataTable and thread safety

Tags: .net, asp.net, multithreading, ado.net, thread-safety

I'm storing DataTable in ASP .NET Cache property. Operations that can be done on that DataTable are:

- binding to grid control (that 3rd party grid internally manages datasource object, after postback its DataSource is NULL, I assume once data is binded it does not use datasource DataTable any more)
- removing rows from DataTable (**Row.Delete()**

I added basic reader/writer locks when explicitly working on that DataTable instance, but I wonder are there any other thread safety issues with that solution. I guess something might go wrong when grid control is in the middle of DataBinding, and other thread removes rows? If so, how can I sync access to that table so that no **Delete** method calls are made when grid control is binding? Are there any combination of events where I can put AcquireWriterLock & ReleaseWriterLock methods ?

Thanks,Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are exposing the datatable via data-binding, then forget it; you cannot make that thread-safe. Even if you wrap the `DataView` somehow (in a custom `ITypedList`), that doesn't do enough - data-binding makes assumptions about the data, in particular the `IList` etc - for example, that it isn't going to randomly change length in a thread-contended way in the middle of iterating the data or adding a row on the UI thread.

There *is* provision for changes *on the same thread* via events ... but not cross-threaded.

Comment: Thanks! What about changing columns values? Will it also cause issues? I could add columns IsDeleted and don't render rows with that flag set.

Comment: @dragonfly but again, you're most likely going to end up raising events from the non-UI thread, which the binding is going to try to react to - again on a non-UI thread. That in turn will most likely do bad things.

Comment: Not good news. So how can I implement caching in safe way.....? DataTable.Copy() and do binding on that copy ?

Comment: About non-UI thread. We're talking about ASP .NET application, so it's not the issue, is it?

Comment: @dragonfly - well, generally you only *cache* immutable data (or at least: treat it as immutable once it is there). Otherwise it isn't a cache...

Comment: @dragonfly if you are talking about ASP.NET, then even worse; DO NOT expose multiple requests to this data if somebody is ever going to edit it.

Comment: The only code that is going to edit it, is my code (in response to one particular event). That data is almost immutable : the reason why I need to cache it is, because query that gets data is very complicated and timeconsuming. And between postbacks only values in one columns change (counters). So I want to cache result for 2 minutes, and when Save operation is done, I want to apply it to database, but instead of fetching query result from DB (which is overkill) I want to modify conunters in disconnected mode. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: @dragonfly there is no "between postbacks" in a web app; you need to assume that crazy access is constant. This *sounds* more like a session thing than cache, which still has some similar issues, of course. Either way, you always have to assume another thread has the same table - it is hard to make any changes safely. How big is it? could you clone it, edit the clone, and swap them? That wouldn't be *as* bad (although you still risk data loss if two edits happen at the exact same time, unless you synchronize all the edits)

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in other answers:

- generally you only cache immutable data (or at least: treat it as immutable once it is there). Otherwise it isn't a cache
- DO NOT expose multiple requests to common data if somebody is ever going to edit it
- If you are exposing the datatable via data-binding, then forget it; you cannot make that thread-safe

However I really needed to cache a DataTable. Reasons:

- query that gets results is really huge & time consuming. Also refresh rate of page that is making a call with that query is big. As a result db engine is becoming bussy. With caching I'll get only 1 db engine call every 2 minutes
- result of that query differs. But it's totally acceptable for the user to see the same result for, let's say, 2 minutes. So storing data in cache for 2 minutes is acceptable. Also there are no other concerns like concurrency, optimistic / pessimistic offline locks...

However when user operates on data it sees, some changes are made to data:

- that change has to be applied on db. Before implementing cache, after change to db was applied application once again issued huge query to get result with only slight differences
- now, with caching, change is applied on db and applied on cached DataTable. Then that data table is binded once again to databound control. Benefits: no need to make WCF call, fetch data using huge query + transfer datatable to web application

This is how I implemented locking for that solution:

1. Cached data is stored in singleton-like wrapper:

   ```
   public class AllocationQueue
   {
       private static object tableSyncRoot = new object();
   ```
2. This is the only piece of code that modifies cached DataTable:

   ```
   internal void RemoveTaskRowFromAllocationQueue(Guid queueId, Guid taskId)
   {
       var allocationQueueEntry = GetAllocationQueueEntry(queueId);
       var queueData = allocationQueueEntry.TaskIdIndexedView;
       lock(tableSyncRoot)
       {
           int rowIndex = queueData.Find(new object[] { taskId });
           queueData[rowIndex].Delete();
       }
   }
   ```
3. This is the only piece of code that exposed data for databinding:

   ```
   public DataTable GetAllocationQueue(Guid queueId, string filter)
   {
       var allocationQueueEntry = GetAllocationQueueEntry(queueId);
       lock (tableSyncRoot)
       {
           var rows = allocationQueueEntry.Table.Select(filter);
           if (rows.Length > 0)
           {
               return rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

Thread-safe & works like a charm (Am I right? :) ). But it's very specyfic to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to add rows in a thread safe manner.  Where dt = my DataTable and dr = my DataRow

```
lock (dt.Rows.SyncRoot)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```