# Set DataGridView.DataSource async

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I must say I've been reading this site for a long time and always found what I was looking for. Sadly, today is not the case.

I have a .NET C# Winforms Application that uses MySQL .NET Connector to query a database and fill a DataGridView with the results.

Here is my code:

```
using (var SqlConn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
{
    using (var SqlComm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM my_database.city", SqlConn)
    {
        using (var SqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SqlComm)
        {
            DataTable SqlOutput = new DataTable();
            SqlAdapter.Fill(SqlOutput);
            myDataGridView.DataSource = SqlOutput;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine. The problem is that, **considering that the table has like 20K rows, it takes some time to load and in the meantime, it blocks UI.**

Doing some tests, I concluded that the database query Fill() its very fast (it actually takes like 10ms). **Therefore, setting DataGridView.DataSource property delays the whole operation**.

So my question is, Is there a way to set DataSource propery async? Or maybe a way where I can still use the form while the data is loading?

I was also wondering if there is a better way of doing this, since I would be calling this method every time I do changes on the database table, so I could show the user updated information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 20K is too much rows to show in `DataGriView`. It's better to load data with paging. Also to prevent UI freeze when loading data use async/await or load data in a different thread than UI thread. [Example: Load data asynchronously into my DataTable in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38427392/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I do have an async/await method that implements MySqlDataAdapter.FillAsync method. But the data pull from the database is not actually freezing the UI, setting the DataSource property does. And I would be still doing that step synchronously. Could you tell me more about loading that with paging?

Comment: So use `DataGridView` in [virtual mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx) or load data paged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation suggests to go with "virualmode"  property setting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

There is other interesting topic "Just in time loading".
Implementing Virtual Mode with Just-In-Time Data Loading in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624(v=vs.110).aspx

You have good examples in above link. Worth looking at them.

Answer (score -1):

Use Thread. Fill your DataGridView Programmatically rather than using DataSource.

```
 public void LoadDataGrid(DataTable d, DataGridView dg )
    {

        if (dg.InvokeRequired)
        {
            dg.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                dg.Rows.Clear();
                dg.ColumnCount = 7;
                dg.Columns[0].Name = "Order No.";
                dg.Columns[0].Width = 110;
                dg.Columns[1].Name = "Order Date";
                dg.Columns[1].Width = 100;
                dg.Columns[2].Name = "Excepted rcv date";
                dg.Columns[2].Width = 100;
                dg.Columns[3].Name = "Supplier";
                dg.Columns[3].Width = 150;
                dg.Columns[4].Name = "Total Items";
                dg.Columns[4].Width = 80;
                dg.Columns[5].Name = "Total";
                dg.Columns[5].Width = 80;
                dg.Columns[6].Name = "Status";
                dg.Columns[6].Width = 100;


            });
            foreach (DataRow row in d.Rows)
            {

                if (dg.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    dg.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { dg.Rows.Add(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString(), row[5].ToString(), row[6].ToString()); });
                }


                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }

    }
```