# Tips on working with Bounded DataGridView and BackGroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

## Problem

I have a `DataGrid` on my form and it is loaded with records from a `DataBase` on `Form_Load` event. I am anticipating that the table would contain a lot of records so I would like to process the loading of the records using a `BackGroundWorker`.

However, since the `DataGrid` is designed on the Visual Studio 2017 forms designer, I only have the `Fill` method to use. If I understood it correctly, the `TableAdapter.Fill` method runs the query and fills my `DataGrid` with the result.

So, when using the `BackGroundWorker` I am not sure how to handle the process of querying, filling and displaying the results on the `DataGrid`

I tried putting the `TableAdapter.Fill` on the `BacgkroundWorker.DoWork` event but the `DataGridView` does not show any records.

The only time that the `DataGridView` shows my record is when the `TableAdapter.Fill` method is placed on the `BackGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Comment: So, have you ditched the `LoadingForm.ShowDialog();`? You really need to show: the BGW declaration, how the Data is loaded, what is the `DataGridView.Datasource` and how it is set. Then, if you want to keep using a BGW, that's fine (you could use a Task), but you should clarify why you need a secondary/non UI thread to load the Data. Do you need to keep the UI responsive at this time? If so, to do what in the meanwhile?

Comment: Hello @Jimi thank you for taking the time to respond to my questions. I think I have actually solved it. I realized that the `TableAdapter` has 2 procedures `GetData` and `Fill`. The `GetData` procedure connects to my database and retrieves the records while the `Fill` procedure fills my `DataSet.DataTable` with the records. I placed the `GetData` on the `BackGroundWorker.DoWork` and developed a mechanism for it to report the progress. Once I have detected that my `GetData` is completed, I can call the `Fill` procedure from the `BackGroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: All right then. Just one (unsolicited) suggestion: if your UI cannot be actually used while the data is loaded (because it's the data content that provides the interaction - grids, lists and such), thus the User has *nothing to do* until the procedure is finished, don't focus that much on the UI responsiveness. When you add a level of complexity to the code, the level of the potential *problems* raises accordingly.

Comment: [Load data asynchronously into DataTable in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427392/3110834)