# What is the correct way to update controls on main UI thread

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

In my C# winforms application I am loading the data from the database using Task in the background, below is my code. But after uploading the data I am updating my UI control(s) which is BindingSource. This BindingSource component is connected to the DataGrid which will be updated as well.

what I need to know is that what I am doing is the right way or is there another better way to achieve the same goal.

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task loadDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
       // LoadData(); // loading the data from the database
    });

    await loadDataTask.ConfigureAwait(true);

    FormBindingSource.DataSource = _businessObjecsCollection;
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that the `DataGrid` may be loaded after the form has been shown to the user.

Comment: [Load data asynchronously into DataTable in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427392/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, great question you suggested. I will try to follow this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can afford it, make method which loads data asynchronous. then you will be able to change Form method as:

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await LoadDataAsync();

    FormBindingSource.DataSource = _businessObjecsCollection;
}
```

maybe even

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    FormBindingSource.DataSource = await LoadDataAsync();
}
```

otherwise current method seems fine