# Updating a DataTable as results are read from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, datatable

I'm building a wpf app in c#.  I want to have a DataGrid that updates with results as they are retrieved from a database (i.e. they display in the DataGrid a row at a time as they are retrieved, very similar to the search function in explorer where the results pop up one at a time as they are found, rather than having a blank results page and then them all appearing at once).

This is my first real attempt at using async methods and multi-threading, so i'm sure there are issues, but that's why i'm experimenting

What i have so far:

- async methods for getting the data from the database.  I have proven that this works.
- Note that i am using direct SQL at the moment for experimenting - once i have this working, i won't be using SQL directly, but stored procedures and parameters
- the database get function is passed a DataTable to allow it to add a row at a time to it as the data is read in:

```
        private static async Task ExecuteTextQueryAsync(string SQLText, OracleConnection conn, DataTable dt)
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(SQLText))
            {
                cmd.BindByName = true;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Connection = conn;

                using (System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) 
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                        foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
                        {
                            string colName = row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
                            Type t = row.Field<Type>("DataType");
                            dt.Columns.Add(colName, t);
                        }
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            var newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                newRow[col.ColumnName] = reader[col.ColumnName];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now as i'm using MVVM, i'm not calling the above method from code behind, but from the view model.  The viewmodel:

- Has a property `DataTable ResultDataGrid` which is bound to the datagrid on the view.
- I've instantiated this DataTable and also added an event handler for TableNewRow event which should run whenever the table has a row added (which then causes NotifyPropertyChanged to be called on the above property
- I'm then trying to run the above data getter on a different thread, and hoping the table would update as new rows were added:

```
using (OracleConnection newConnection = Helper.CreateConnectionAsync(ConnectionStr).Result)
            {
                try
                {
                    var task = Task.Run(async () => { await Helper.ExecuteTextQueryAsync("Select * from LargeNumberOfRowsTable", newConnection, dt); });
                }
```

Like i said, i have confirmed that the results are being correctly read from the database, however the event handler for TableNewRow never fires.

Is it possible for another thread to fire events on the calling thread?

Am i completely on the wrong track for reading the results in and updating the table as they come in?  I feel like i'm close, but my lack of knowledge on threads is letting me down.

Comment: Whenever you are talking about real time and Windows, you are on the wrong track. Windows is **not** a real time OS. Any action will happen as soon as possible and that can even be some seconds later => not real time

Comment: Agreed - i didn't mean real time in the technical sense, i just mean that the rows would appear in effect one by one, with the result being similar to a search type function - this would give feedback to the end user that results are loading and a feeling of how fast they are being retrieved.  I'd probably also put up some sort of in progress graphic and also disable the grid to prevent selections until the grid is full loaded.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think you need to first `var newRow = dt.NewRow();` then `/* Set values on newRow */` and finally `dt.Rows.Add(newRow);`

Comment: ...and have you confirmed that all of this works, before trying to offload it to a new thread?

Comment: When you compare this to a search function, do you mean like the user manually triggers an update/reload of the data? Or it is continuously _monitoring_ that database table and displaying new data as fast as its able? Also, I'm not seeing an empty `Rows.Add()` overload and the [`TableNewRow` event](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.tablenewrow) doesn't do what you think it does: "Fires after a new `DataRow` has been created using `NewRow`. ... The new `DataRow` instance is detached; it has not been added to the collection." Try `RowChanged` when `e.Action` is `Add`.

Comment: I tested it works in isolation, that is the datatable is fully loaded if i run this synchronously.  However, i can't get it to work on its own thread - i either get "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'" or if i task.wait for it to finish then it completes fine.  I think there is an issue calling the TableNewRow event handler from the other thread.  Not sure how to marshall it though - i've tried:

Comment: Dispatcher dispatcher = CurrentApp.Dispatcher;

            if (!dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    base.NotifyPropertyChanged("ResultDataGrid");
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                base.NotifyPropertyChanged("ResultDataGrid");
            }

Comment: Thanks to BACON - i've changed the event to the RowChanged event.  Also thanks to rfmodulator tweaked the loading as suggested.  Still the issue above, not sure how to stop the invalidoperationexception

Comment: Sounds like progress, I have to leave soon, I just wanted to mention that the `DataAdapter` does some built-in async stuff these days, and it saves you from building the `DataTable` schema manually ...assuming it's offered for Oracle, but I don't know why it wouldn't be.

Comment: Got a bad feeling that i can't bind to something that is being updated by another thread (i.e. in this case the DataTable).  Can't really think of another way to populate the table, and update the UI as each row is loaded though.

Comment: Yep confirmed this is the issue, if i create a new DataTable and use this new DataTable in ExecuteTextQueryAsync and I await the ExecuteTextQueryAsync, then assign this DataTable to my bound ResultDataGrid then there are no exceptions, and the datagrid shows all the data.  This keeps my UI responsive, however, due to awaiting the get, there is no data, then all the data appears at once.  Racking my brains on how to get the DataGrid to update as the data is read

Comment: Yep, according to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744588/datatable-and-thread-safety?rq=1 it seems like DataTable can't be bound and updated by a different thread.  I'm going to try using Master and Slave tables - i pass the master table to the database function, but bind to a different 'slave' table.  When master updates, i'll copy the master to the slave using the UI thread.  Seems very wasteful, and i'm not entirely convinced it will work - any other suggestions welcome.

Comment: OK my suggestion above didn't work and gave me the worst error i've ever seen:

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.
  See the inner exception for more information.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Verify()
...

Comment: Inner Exception 1:
Exception: Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):
This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:3047' with name '(unnamed)' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
  Accumulated count 22 is different from actual count 3047.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

Comment: I'm not even going to try and deal with that one, so i guess i'm giving up!  I'm not sure why such a simple sounding requirement is so hard to achieve, so i suspect i have embarked on completely the wrong direction, rather than only being slightly out.  I guess i'm just going to have to wait for the results to all just pop up, rather than seeing them coming in :-(